# Recommendations for SMS gateways with API-support

Tags: api

I'm building a web application that needs to send notifications by SMS.

What SMS gateway service providers with API support fulfill the following requirements:

- Reliable
- Global delivery - I will send globally with no specific region being sent to more than others
- Ideally cheap

What are your recommendations? Why?

Comment: Pekka: The servers sending the SMS:es will be located in US, Europe and Asia. How is that relevant? :-)

Comment: Normaly the prices are different in each country, it depends of traffic.

Comment: favelgue: I will send globally with no specific region being sent to more than other.

Comment: nice options here for asp.net  http://forums.asp.net/t/1918083.aspx?Need+to+send+a+free+SMS+from+my+asp+net+application

Comment: http://socialcompare.com/en/comparison/sms-gateways-1odvv6xv

Answer (score 39, accepted):

[**Clickatell**](http://www.clickatell.com/products/sms%5Fgateway.php) is a popular SMS gateway, which [covers 819 networks in over 220 countries](http://www.clickatell.com/pricing/standard_mt_coverage.php).

The API offers a choice of connection options via: **[HTTP/S](http://www.clickatell.com/developers/api_http.php), [SMPP](http://www.clickatell.com/developers/api_smpp.php), [SMTP](http://www.clickatell.com/developers/api_smtp.php), [FTP](http://www.clickatell.com/developers/api_ftp.php), [XML](http://www.clickatell.com/developers/api_xml.php), [SOAP](http://www.clickatell.com/developers/api_soap.php) and [COM](http://www.clickatell.com/developers/api_comobject.php)**.

---

To give a few examples, the **HTTP method** would be as simple as requesting the following URI from your application:

```
http://api.clickatell.com/http/sendmsg?to=NUMBER&msg=Message+Body+Here
```

The **SMTP method** would consist in sending a plain-text email to `sms@messaging.clickatell.com`, with a body as in the following example:

```
user: xxxxx
password: xxxxx
api_id: xxxxx
to: NUMBER
text: Message Body Here
```

The other methods are similarly easy to interface with, in my opinion. You can check out the full details from the [Clickatell API Guide](http://support.clickatell.com/guides/clickatell/api_guide.php).

---

As for message costs, Clickatell uses a credit based system. 1 credit will generally mean 1 message, but some destinations may charge a bit less (usually 0.8 of a credit) and some may charge more (usually 1.5 or 2). Apparently this depends on the network operators in the particular region. ([Source](http://www.clickatell.com/pricing/message_cost.php))

**1 credit** is currently priced at **USD 0.03 / EUR 0.022 / GBP 0.02**. There is a minimum requirement of 400 credits, so the initial investment can be of just USD 12. ([Source](http://www.clickatell.com/pricing/payment_methods.php))

---

You may also want to test the gateway for free from your browser: [Clickatell: Test SMS Gateway](http://www.clickatell.com/products/test_gateway.php).

Comment: https://www.smsgateway.to/en

Answer (score 4):

We've been using [MxTelecom](http://www.mxtelecom.com) for a few years and are very happy with them.

Answer (score 4):

I've used clickatell (www.clickatell.com) for sending msgs to Europe, US and AsiaPac destinations. Prices are cheap, depending on destination & quantity - there is an online calculator you can use to estimate costs. The API is simple (HTTP REST). They also support two-way, bulk and MMS messaging service, but I have not used these.

I have had trouble getting messages sent to some carriers in Malaysia, but their support team was responsive and this issue was resolved within about 10 days.

I also like the online reporting tools which provides graphs of messages sent / success rates etc over time.

Answer (score 3):

[Panacea Mobile](http://www.panaceamobile.com) offers HTTP, SMPP and SMTP API connectivity. They, too, have global coverage and offer the cheapest rates with such an advanced API. Have a look at this PHP script featured here: bakery.cakephp.org/articles/view/component-to-send-sms-text-messages

You can also view the Panacea Mobile API Guide on the support site - look under the API guides.

You can view their pricing by volume and country on the sms gateway page.

Answer (score 2):

[Clickatell](http://www.clickatell.com/) is pretty good.

Comment: Please expand - why is it so? :-)

Comment: @knorv Because it meets the requirements you asked for.

Comment: silky: Have you used Clickatell? What has been good? What has been bad? :-)

Comment: I think it is not cheap and it is not mostly used out of US

Comment: @fravelgue You are wrong on both counts (IMHO); we use it here in Australia and in the UK, and it's international anyway. Indeed, it is also reasonably cheap, from my experience.

Comment: @knorv: Yes, I've used them. It's trivial to integrate, you have a few options (email/http/xml). The bad? nothing. Set it up, made it work, forgot about it. What more could you ask for.

Comment: @silky, i know it is international. But i have check his prices in markets where my compamy operate and our price are more cheep.
We work with more of 10 world-wide aggregators. Sry but i cannot give names, but if you need more information, you can connect private with me.

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest looking into [OpenMarket](http://www.openmarket.com/) for SMS, Premium SMS as well as MMS, they offer several SDK's in a number of languages.

FYI: MX Telecom was purchased by OpenMarket/Amdocs

Answer (score 1):

we've been using [iMEZ](http://www.imez.se/home.aspx) and no problems so far.

Answer (score 0):

Would suggest http://sms2email.com/site/email2sms.php They provide various features sms, mms, bulk features, ringtone gateway. Pricing comes in credits and different pricing for bulk features. Integration also simple.