# Web application control through text messages

Tags: sms, vs-web-application-project

I want to develop an application that works by receiving text messages from users to gather data. I have no clue where to begin and what to begin with. I can code in Python, C++, PHP and can do Java also.

I was wondering if there can be a personal development setup or framework on which I can develop such application. Releasing it is a different story but I do not have any idea about what setup is needed to develop this application.

Also, how much would this setup cost? Are there open-source or any other cheap alternatives?

Comment: possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2383542/recommendations-for-sms-gateways-with-api-support

Comment: That is about sending messages. I want to receive them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a lot of services out there that let you receive SMS via a web request. The one I work for Twilio will send you a simple POST request to a URL of your choice containing To, From and Body whenever you receive an incoming message. You can [read more about how it works here](http://www.twilio.com/sms/).

Comment: Hi John, I know Twilio provides City/State location, if available, but I need more than that. I needed to map those within the city area...is that possible? I want to map the incoming messages to the location in the city.

Comment: SMS messages do not contain any real-time geolocation data. The location data we send is for the number, not the current location of the sender. Location sent with a text message would be a huge privacy problem since there's no opportunity to opt in/out. Youd have to build a smart phone app for that.

Comment: Thanks John. That explains a lot. So, I think there is no service that will provide that kind of location for text messages? Opt-in and out should be done by sending text messages or reporting that to the carrier, ?

Comment: There is no service that does current location over SMS automatically. You could maybe ask for it but that would be had to parse from free text. If this is a requirement, you'll need to build a smartphone app

Comment: The reason I am going for text messaging is because I need this service to be available to masses and SMS/Text Messages give more reach for this web service. I am surprised to know that there is no such service at this moment.

Answer (score 0):

[This](http://www.2-waysms.com/?page=sms_receiving) service offers an api for receiving text messages. You can use the shared number and send it to your server with a keyword or you can pay a monthy  fee to have your own dedicated number. So there would be a good place to start.