# how to send SMS to remote server/databse and get data in mobile phone

Tags: php, mobile, jquery-mobile, sms

I have a small application written in PHP and a mysql database hosted on a remote server. The database structure is like following:

```
id      name            password
001    Bon Jovi          123 
002    Charlie Sheen     456
```

Now what I want to achieve is, I will SMS the id and password using my mobile phone (although I don't know where exactly to send) to the server(in this case I don't how it would be possible) and in return I want to know the name from my database.

Example: If I write 001,123 in my mobile's message option and then send to my server(I don't know how)and i want to get the name "Bon Jovi" as feed back.

Would you please kindly tell me if what I want to achieve is possible, and if then how?

Thanks in Advance :)

Comment: You cannot access your web server from SMS. You can access it through mobile data, but not SMS.

Comment: Thanks nav_nav .would you please kindly explain a bit how can I access to my server through mobile data ?

Comment: @nav_nav Not directly, but through an SMS gateway yes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a few different options covered previously.  Of those available, I think the leader at this point is [Twilio,](http://www.twilio.com/) who provides a well thought out REST interface that allows you to send and receive SMS messages.

However see [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2383542/recommendations-for-sms-gateways-with-api-support) for more ideas.